# Symfony2: How to get the authentication provider for a logged in user?

Tags: symfony, authentication

I need to find out the current authentication provider which authenticated the `TokenInterface` in my Symfony2 application. The main reason for that is to check how the user logged in, in order to provide appropriate logout methods.

Is there any way to do that? If so, how?

Comment: Looking at `\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutUrlGenerator::generateLogoutUrl()` it does not seem trivial to get the provider key. Also this [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12160) might help.